# Convert POJO List to CSV comma delimited String

Tags: java, spring, csv

I have a List of `ProcessedClass` (POJO I have created) that I would like to generate to a string of comma-delimited values. So all items in the list output to a single, comma-delimited list.

My plan is to: pass the list into a method, iterate through the list and append commas and finally remove the last comma and return the resulting string. The object being processed will have some nested POJO's with multiple different variable types (`string`, `int`, `boolean`, other POJO's, `LocalDate` etc..). I have added an example of the structure below.

My question is what is the best way to go about constructing this? Thank you in advance.

Example structure being processed:

```
//List<ProcessedClass> will be passed into the iternation method
public class ProcessedClass {

    private Other other;

    private Info info;
}

public class Other {

    private String stringMessage;

    private boolean booleanValue;
    
    ...
}

public class Info {
    //Another defined POJO
    private User user;

    private LocalDate date;

    private String name;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Nested objects in a CSV file are not that straightforward. Why not JSON?

Comment: Unfortunately JSON cannot be used for my purpose, I need to return a string that will then be passed straight into a csv on the client-side. I am currently exploring flattening the POJO into a new class and then appending the new class info

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringJoiner` with `,` delimiter.

```java
StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");
processedClasses.forEach(a -> stringJoiner.add(a.toString()));
System.out.println(stringJoiner);
```

Of course, you have to implement the `toString` method in all defined classes.